# sscanf multiple inputs

Tags: c++, c, input, scanf

I have an input string that I need to parse to get anywhere from 4 - 16 variables. Using sscanf I can get the first few variables but the rest show as 0. What do I need to do to get the rest?

Line format: COMMAND [1 - 16 float variables separated by a space]

The line is coming in from a file using something like this:

fgets(line, 20, file);

sscanf(line, "%s", param);

string parString(param);

if(parString == "NEAR"){

```
      sscanf(line, "%s %f", param, &np);
      printf("%s %f\n", param, np);
```

}...

Depending on the first word in the line I know how many variables I need to read in for that case.

Comment: How is the input string defined? Can we have an example of what you're trying to parse please! Oh, and your code. You know, the usual questions...

Comment: @Joe an example line would be 
"SPHERE s3 -4 2 -10 2 2 1 0 0 0.5 0 0 1 0 1000"

Comment: In re `fgets(line, 20, file)` is 20 really enough space to hold your entire line?

Answer (score 1):

This task would be much better done with a `std::istringstream` because it remembers the position you've read to so far. So you could write code like this

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream input("SPHERE s3 -4 2 -10 2 2 1 0 0 0.5 0 0 1 0 1000");
int var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6;
// get first four variables
input >> var1 >> var2 >> var3 >> var4;
if (something or other)
{
    // get the next two variables
    input >> var5 >> var6;
}
```

Something like that anyway. I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

One way in C would be to use [**strtok()**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtok_r.html).

```
char *p = strtok(str, " ");

while(p)
{
// Store each string 
// OR convert it to integer using strtol() if an intger was expected
p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

The loop will terminate when there are no more values to read from `str`.